# The different of a Galois extension of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Since the ramification indices of a prime are the same in a Galois extension, the following proposition is likely to be true.
If it is true, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $K$ be an algebraic number field.
Let $L$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $L/K$.
Let $\mathfrak{D}_{L/K}$ be the different.
Then $\sigma(\mathfrak{D}_{L/K}) = \mathfrak{D}_{L/K}$ for every $\sigma \in G$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it better to use the defn of *inverse* different as the "dual module" to the integers $\mathfrak o_L$ under trace to $K$? That is,
$$
\hbox{inverse different}\;=\;
\{\alpha\in L\;:\; \hbox{tr}^L_K(\alpha\cdot \mathfrak o_L)\subset \mathfrak o_K\}
$$
Trace is certainly Galois-invariant, and taking inverse of a fractional ideal is, also.

Comment: The easiest proof depends on the definition of the different. There are at least 4 different definitions of the different. Your definition is the most often used, though.

Comment: I am slightly surprised to hear that there are other definitions, but maybe I've just not been paying attention: apart from using this definition to bound ramification, and to give a name to the dual module under the trace pairing for Iwasawa-Tate theory and such, I've not seen other characterizations.

Comment: The different was first defined by Dedekind.
He defined it as $GCD$ of all $f'(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is an integer of $L$ generating $L$ over $K$ and $f(X)$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.
There is the Hilbert's definition. I posted a question about it a while ago.
The diffferent can be defined as the annihilator of the Kähler differential module $\Omega_{B/A}$.